# nephesh chay (breath of life) vs neshamah chay (breath of life) vs chay nephesh (living being) in Genesis 2

Tags: genesis

A related question is [Are the three distinctive Hebrew terms, translated "breath of life," suggesting there was a different mankind at creation than there was at the flood?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/22276/are-the-three-distinctive-hebrew-terms-translated-breath-of-life-suggesting).

Berean Study Bible, Genesis 1:30

> And to every beast [chay] of the earth and every bird of the air and every creature that crawls upon the earth—everything that has the **breath** [h5315 נָ֫פֶשׁ nephesh] of **life** [h2416 חָי chay] in it—I have given every green plant for food.” And it was so.

The breath of life here is nephesh chay נֶ֣פֶשׁ חַיָּ֔ה

Berean Study Bible, Genesis 2:7

> Then the LORD God formed man from the dust of the ground and breathed the **breath** [h5397 נְשָׁמָה neshamah] of **life** [h2416 חָי chay] into his nostrils, and the man became a **living** [chay] **being** [nephesh].

Now, the breath of life is neshamah chay נִשְׁמַ֣ת חַיִּ֑ים

What is the difference between these 2 instances of "breath of life"?

How are they different from living being (chay nephesh)?